# Difference between hyper graph to bipartite graph

Tags: graph-theory

What is the difference between a bipartite graph and a hypergraph?

Can I assume that a directed hypergraph is also a directed bipartie graph?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A [hypergraph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergraph) is a generalisation of a graph, with hyperedges which might not contain exactly two vertices, as edges do in a graph.  A [bipartite graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipartite_graph) is a special kind of a graph.

Thus, we might write $$\text{bipartite graphs} \subsetneq \text{graphs} \subsetneq \text{hypergraphs}.$$

E.g. any hypergraph with a hyperedge that contains $3$ vertices is not even a graph, and thus not a bipartite graph.

In general, a directed hypergraph would look nothing like a directed bipartite graph.

---

Actually, I think I might have an idea why this question would be asked.

In something like a [chemical reaction network](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chemical_reaction_network_theory), a directed hyperedge has multiple inputs and multiple outputs.  If we had chemical reactants $\{a,b,c\}$ and chemical products $\{X,Y\}$, then we have the directed hyperedge $(\{a,b,c\},\{X,Y\})$.  We can turn this directed hyperedge into the six directed edges $\{aX,aY,bX,bY,cX,cY\}$.

By replacing every directed hyperedge in this manner, we can obtain a directed bipartite graph.  (This came up once in my research into [biological neural networks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biological_neural_network), and the massive increase in edge density as a result of this operation thwarted my analysis.)

However, it seems difficult to define a reverse process; it would require the detection of directed bicliques (and it's not even clear that the process would be reversible).

Comment: In a chemical reaction network, which is exatly why i asked this question. I could represent reactions as a directed hyperedge form, lets say r1 = ({a,b,c},{d,e}), however same could be done with a bipartie graph such both reactions and species are vertex and r1 would be arcs ({a,r1},{b,r1},{c,r1},{r1,d},{r1,e}) such that reactions and species form two disjoin sets of vertex. So i taugh if in this scenario every hypergrah could be translated to bipartite graphs and vice versa.

Comment: You can go from this kind of directed hypergraph to a directed bipartite graph, but I don't think it's possible to go back (but it shouldn't be a big deal: you probably know both the directed hypergraph and the directed bipartite graph anyway).

Comment: E.g. the directed hyperedges ({a,b},{x,y}), ({a,c},{x,z}) and ({b,c},{y,z}) would give rise to the same directed bipartite graph as the single directed hyperedge ({a,b,c},{x,y,z}).

Comment: To make this isomorphic the bipartite graph needs all information in the hypergraph. Hyperedges are labeled so add those labels in the bipartite graph. Some nodes are external so add this as label in the bipartite graph. The connected nodes of hyperedges are ordered so add those as edge labels in the bipartite graph.I think that should be sufficient to define an isomorphic mapping?